# Swift 5 Labeled Break

Tags: swift

I have a function that is checking a connection and it tries multiple times.  That said, the actual connection attempt takes time and trying to cut off as much time as possible for the user to wait.  So if the first attempt works I just want to break out of the loop but can't figure it out.  So have the below:

```
func CheckVPNConnetionLoop()
{
    for _ in 1...2
      {
        checkConnection
          {
            (isOnline) -> Void in
            let status = isOnline!
            DispatchQueue.main.async
              {
                if status
                  {
                     break out of the for loop totally
                  }
                else
                  {
                    wait for a few seconds
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

So I tried the below label but it says it can't find it in scope.  Also tried just break and that didn't work.

```
func CheckVPNConnetionLoop()
{
    TEST:    for _ in 1...2
      {
        checkConnection
          {
            (isOnline) -> Void in
            let status = isOnline!
            DispatchQueue.main.async
              {
                if status
                  {
                    break TEST
                  }
                else
                  {
                    <wait for a few seconds>
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

EDIT:  Added  checkConnection function:

```
func checkConnection(completionHandler:@escaping (_ isOnline: Bool?) -> Void){
    let stringurl = "http://" + "1.1.1.1"
    let url = NSURL(string: stringurl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if (httpResponse?.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String) != nil {
            let isConnected = true
            completionHandler(isConnected)
        }else{
            let isConnected = false
            completionHandler(isConnected)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Is `checkConnection` asynchronous? If so, your loop isn't going to function as you're expecting it to. Both iterations will finish practically instantaneously.

Comment: Added checkConnection above.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is as I suspected. You shouldn’t be using a loop at all here.

Comment: I'd suggest making a function that calls `checkConnection` and then calls it again after a delay if the result isn't a valid connection. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: can you use swift 5.5 with the async/await features?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I do know how to do as your suggesting jnpdx.  Right now I've removed the loop and seeing how bulletproof it is without any retries.  Since apparently it wasn't doing much though now that I've removed it can see the double check was doing something as takes less time now to get past that routine.  Also with workingdog's comment, have to look into that.  Not familiar with await.

Comment: my comment was just to ask about the system you are using, are you on macos 12 and using xcode 13.beta, targeting ios 15? If not then you cannot use async/await

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to try multiple times connecting to the server.
Tested on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst.
It should also work on macos 11.x and ios 14.x.

Note it will block the main thread for the chosen amount of time.
It will require a bit more work to make this work on a background thread.
This is to get you going.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let nTries = 3
    @State var urlString = "https://1.1.1.1"  // <-- note https
    @State var msg = "checking connection"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(msg)
        .onAppear {
            // this is the test
            tryConnect(wait: 3, retry: nTries) { isConnected in
                msg = isConnected ? "can connect" : "could not connect"
            }
        }
    }
 
    func checkConnection(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("invalid url error") // <-- todo deal with errors
            return completion(false)
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                // assuming this is what you want to check
                if (httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String) != nil {
                    return completion(true)
                } else {
                    return completion(false)
                }
            }
            return completion(false)
        }.resume()
    }
    
    // wait is the time in seconds between retries, retry is the number of retries
    func tryConnect(wait: TimeInterval, retry: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        guard (retry > 0 && wait > 0) else { return completion(false) }
        self.checkConnection() { isConnected in
            if !isConnected {
                msg = "trying: \(nTries + 1 - retry)" // <-- just for testing
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: wait)   // <-- this is where it waits before the next try
                if retry != 1 {
                    return self.tryConnect(wait: wait, retry: retry-1) { isCon in
                        completion(isCon)
                    }
                } else {
                    return completion(false)
                }
            }
            return completion(true)
        }
    }
 
}
```